# how to loop a parameter from a table column in httpclient

Tags: c#

I would like to ask how am I going to add a foreach loop within this httpclient codes. I'm new to this.

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var url = new Uri(URL+ "/GetAll");
        var content = new StringContent("{Code: '(this should be taken from a table column)'}");

        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var objResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SrpResult>(result);

        var jsonlist = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objResult, Formatting.Indented);

        var str = "EXEC dbo.JSON @json";
        Sql.ExecNonQuery(str, jsonlist);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var url = new Uri(IAMSUrl + "/GetSRP");
    var content = new StringContent("{CustomerCode: '(this should be taken from a table column)'}");

    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var objResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SrpResult>(result);

    var jsonlist = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objResult, Formatting.Indented);

    var str = "EXEC dbo.JSONToTEPP_SRP @json";
    foreach(var json in jsonlist)
    {
        Sql.ExecNonQuery(str, json); 
    }
}
```

Comment: i just need to pull out the parameter from a table column and create a loop for that. does that makes sense?

Comment: @JEROMI Ok, should the Sql.ExecNonQuery() return a row from which you need to fetch a column value?